# How to use an image for a button in Ionic Framework based on *ngIf

Tags: image, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I'm using the ion-icon name="md-image" for uploading images to firebase storage.  Once that image is uploaded, *ngIf="image" I want the image to replace the button.  Currently the image is only partially covering the icon button.

```
        <button ion-button color="secondary" type="button" full round 
         large (click)="selectPhoto()">
                <img *ngIf="test" [src]="test"/>
                <ion-icon name="md-image"></ion-icon>
        </button>
```

[image: Notice the 2d button is only partially covered when *ngIf="true"]

How do I replace the entire upload button with an image when it resolves to true?

Comment: Do you want to replace the ion icon

Comment: do you want to replace the button or the icon?

Comment: Yes.  I want to replace the ion icon by the image once the image is uploaded.

Comment: I'm trying a different strategy but can't find the correct syntax.  I want to use an *ngSwitch based on the src "test".  How do you word this in the case where the image source is null || undefined so that it uses the ionic image?